# Avoiding redundancy in checking the return values from C subroutines?

Tags: c

There is so much redundancy in the following code:

```
int init( )
{
    int err;

    err = init_a();
    if(err)
        return -1;

    err = init_b();
    if(err)
        return -1;

    err = init_c();
    if(err)
        return -1;

   // etc.

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way of checking the `err` return values?

Comment: in this case `if (init_a() || init_b() || init_c()) return -1;`

Comment: There are *different* ways, to be sure. "Better" is a matter of opinion. What you have now is a *dream* to debug. Since you don't seem to care one bit about the *value* of `err` beyond whether or not it is non-zero you could always `return (init_a() || init_b() || init_c()) ? -1 : 0;`, but it would be overtly cryptic and a PITA to debug.

Comment: You may think this is "redundant" but to me it reads clear and obvious. Code is for humans, not machines. It should be simple and easy to follow, which this is.

Comment: I think you need to specify "better way" or you are just asking for broad, subjective opinions.

Comment: `init(){return a()|b()|c()?-1:0;}` is a better way since it wins in Code Golf. Just ignore that all functions are always executed - because this code is obviously "better".

Answer (score 2):

If you really have large numbers of init functions and are not afraid of function pointers,

```
#include <stddef.h>

int init_a(void), init_b(void), init_c(void);
int init(void);

static int (*const func[])(void) = {
    &init_a,
    &init_b,
    &init_c,
    // etc.
};

#define ELEMENTS(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int init(void) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ELEMENTS(func); ++i) {
        if (func[i]() != 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For another init_x() all you need to do is insert it at the appropriate index of the func[] array. It's also super easy, barely an inconvenience, to swap around and delete functions. You could even `return 1 + i;` if you want to know which function failed.

Now your init() has become *data driven* by the func[] array (as opposed to *code driven* by statements in init()).

This only works if your init_* functions have the same prototype and take the same arguments, if any.

Comment: I like these kind of code, but you have to be absolutly sure that every init_ fonction take and will take the same parameter, otherwise you end up writting needlesly complex code.

Comment: This should be `int (*const func[])(void)`. Don't allocate these on the stack.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, I have modified the code according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Short-circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
bool init( )
{
    return init_a() || init_b() || init_c();
}
```

If you can accept using a boolean value as final indication of success or failure (in my example failure = `true`), then [Short-circuiting operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) can make things quite compact.

The C language employs short-circuiting, so in a logical expression with several operands, the code will only execute "as far as is needed" to deduce the final value of the expression.  So if `A` is true in the expression `A || B || C` then `B` and `C` will not be evaluated. If none of the init_N() functions return failure, then the return value will be success.

You can of course negate the logic if you prefer success = `true` with `return A && B && B` (but your code suggests success is `false`)

Also, if you want to allow the cause of the error, ie an error code, to be reported back to the caller, just pass in a pointer to an error code, and let all sub-inits set it to something useful:

```
bool init(int* err)
{
    return init_a(err) || init_b(err) || init_c(err);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. This notation will be familiar to those with experience in shell scripting and should result in efficient binary code. It will, however, require rewriting to distinguish between different causes of failure.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping the separate init functions would "print" something.   However, one could even: `bool init(int* err) { return init_a(err) || init_b(err) || init_c(err); }` and let an actual error code propagate back to the caller. (Added this as an option)

Comment: `int init_a (int* err)` makes for a strange API though, returning the error code both through the return value and a parameter. I'd accuse anyone inventing an interface like that for obfuscation. Also, as someone already said, this `||` chain will be a major pain to debug. And it doesn't scale well during maintenance. There's just two sensible implementations here IMO: either what the OP already had or the function pointer table called from a loop.

Comment: I think you confused lazy-evaluation with what in C is called *short-circuiting* operators. They are quite different concepts.

Comment: @Jens TIL this is called [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which can be a consequence of [Lazy Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Thanks!

Comment: @Lundin I've seen similar where the passed pointer parameters are only valid if SUCCESS was returned.  I am mainly focusing on the _brevity_ part of the question.   But I agree, it isn't a recommended way of writing maintainable code...

Comment: C really doesn't have any of the lazy evaluation goodies, like deferred evaluation and such. If you try to sell C as a language capable of lazy evaluation you will oversell it drastically. More likely, you will confuse your readers. Short circuiting is an implicit boolean test, not exactly rocket science. Comprehensive lazy evaluation is part of functional programming and totally rocket science. Any C programmer calls the properties of `&&` and `||` short circuiting, so do the language designers K&R. No one calls it lazy evaluation, really.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for this, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If these initialization sub-processes must be called in order, which is common in hardware/driver software, status check after each step is necessary. In your example, return a different error code is more indicative.

```
int init(void) {
  int err = init_a();
  if (0 != err) {
    return -1;
  }

  err = init_b();
  if (0 != err) {
    return -2;
  }

  err = init_c();
  if (0 != err) {
    return -3;
  }

  // etc.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71139443/2115408) pretty much covers both error propagation AND is very compact

Answer (score 1):

> There is so much redundancy in the following code:

I don't know about that.  There is a *repeating motif*, which I guess is what you are talking about, but nothing there is redundant.  If you are looking for DRYer code, then this sort of thing can be addressed with the help of preprocessor macros:

```
#define RETURN_IF_NZ(x, r) do { if (x) return (r); } while (0)

int init(void) {
    RETURN_IF_NZ(init_a(), -1);
    RETURN_IF_NZ(init_b(), -1);
    RETURN_IF_NZ(init_c(), -1);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Among the advantages are:

- No (explicit) repetition of the error-handling code
- The behavior of the function is more easily followed (once the macro is understood) because the key elements are less obscured by error-handling scaffolding

Among the disadvantages are:

- Not as easy to debug as the original version (but easier than some alternatives that have been presented)
- Humans have to know, guess, or look up the meaning of the macro

Macro usage is poorly regarded by some, on the basis that functions should be preferred for most purposes. However, this is among the cases that macros can handle, but functions can't.

Comment: Must say I was thinking in the "macro direction". Thanks for your effort.